# How to sort by name in alphabets using mysql query

Tags: mysql

MY albums are sorted by id , now i would like to show only album only B alphabet.

My old query

```
$valueql_select="SELECT DISTINCT (i.gallery_album_id) FROM mov_gallery_album AS a, mov_gallery_images AS i WHERE a.gallery_album_id = i.gallery_album_id AND a.gallery_cat_id =".$_GET['cat']." ORDER BY gallery_id desc";
```

I tried by using LIKE

```
$valueql_select="SELECT DISTINCT (i.gallery_album_id) FROM mov_gallery_album AS a, mov_gallery_images AS i WHERE a.gallery_album_id = i.gallery_album_id AND a.gallery_cat_id =".$_GET['cat']." ORDER BY name LIKE 'b%'";
```

But the above query doesn't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the condition in the WHERE clause:

```
$valueql_select="SELECT DISTINCT i.gallery_album_id
                 FROM mov_gallery_album AS a
                 JOIN mov_gallery_images AS i
                 ON a.gallery_album_id = i.gallery_album_id
                 WHERE a.gallery_cat_id = '42'
                 AND name LIKE 'b%'
                 ORDER BY name";
```

Also you have an SQL injection vulnerability. Do **not** concatenate values into your SQL string. Especially when they are directly from user input without any validation.

**Related**

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sort these names which start with `B` first try this:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN name name LIKE 'b%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, name ;
```

And if you want to get these names that start with `B`'s you have to move the `LIKE` predicate to the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
WHERE a.gallery_album_id = i.gallery_album_id 
 AND a.gallery_cat_id =".$_GET['cat']."
 AND name LIKE 'b%'
 ORDER BY name
```